# Firefox plugin for mobile web development?

Tags: firefox

I am looking for a Firefox plugin so that I can see the effect of a page on mobile devices without physically shrinking the browser window.

I am hoping to see a dropdown on the Firefox top menu bar area. The dropdown lists various sizes, and I can select one to see how the website looks like in the selected window size (but the browser window does not change in size). I also hope that I can reload the page (after code modification) and still see the mobile display.

Is there anything like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is already a feature in vanilla ff, look in web developer submenu of the main menu, for responsive design option

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing it out!